# SQL Server indexes overlap

Tags: sql-server

I am going through a legacy database, and I am wanting to check my understanding of indexes before I start cleaning things up.

Looking at these 3 example indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_1 ON MyTable (id);
CREATE INDEX IX_2 ON MyTable (id, block);
CREATE INDEX IX_3 ON MyTable (id) INCLUDE (dateDone);
```

My understanding is that any query that would use `IX_1`, can perform equally as well with either `IX_2` or `IX_3`.

Or is there a benefit to keeping `IX_1`?

Could all of these be replaced with:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_4 ON MyTable (id, block) INCLUDE (dateDone)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, that is correct.** All of them can be replaced with `IX_4`. Any query filtering just on `id` can use any index whose leading key column is `id`.

There are very particular circumstances when you would not do so: when queries are *only* querying the `id` column, and would benefit from reading a narrower index. But this is predicated on the other columns being particularly wide, for example `varchar(8000)` or `varchar(max)`, and that it is going to be scanning all or a large portion of that index, rather than just a single row. Otherwise it's probably not worth the cost of maintaining the extra index.

Comment: One bit of pedantry - to paraphrase one of our modern poets: "mo' columns, mo' problems". Which in this case means that the more columns you have in the index, the more that updates to those columns will need to do. To use the specifics of OP's question, if any of `ID`, `block` or `dateDone` are volatile (i.e. updated a lot), the cost of keeping those indexes up to date with respect to the new value could outweigh the cost of doing the key lookup on a `select`. TL;DR - "it depends".

Comment: Arguably if queries on those columns are also frequent then it's still worth it. Essentially all of that is rolled into the "probably not worth the cost" as  you need to know the cost of index maintenance to understand whether or not to do so.

Comment: 100% agreed. But since you and I know neither the velocity of select or update queries on which these indexes are involved, the only responsible advice we can give is "you need to know your workload in order to make an informed choice". Not only for OP but for anyone who stumbles across this in the future.